# Memory address value change listener

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

Is it possible programmatically using VC++ to wait for the value of specific memory address to change and then do something with it without the infinite loop? To get the value I'm using **ReadProcessMemory** function.

Comment: You could make a thread that keeps reading the memory until the address changes.

Comment: @bhazero025
That's what I'm currently doing. I'm looking for another way, because that method uses 12% of my processor.

Comment: Clarification: Can we safely assume you are snooping some other process and not your own?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes. I'm reading addresses of another process, which is a program created by me.

Comment: How soon after the change do you need to know about the change? You may be able to set a 1ms tick and sleep for a millisecond. You should  know within about 2 ms.

Comment: @user4581301
I've got no time limits so everything within 1s should work. The 1ms sleep solved the problem. 0% processor usage. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't matter, but I recommend a quick test to make sure you really got a 1 ms tick. You may find yourself asking for 1 ms and getting the standard Windows tick of 15.625 ms. Might be useful to know so you don't get a nasty surprise later.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the same way Visual Studio does data breakpoints:

As long as your program will only ever run on X86 processors, and as system administrator, you should be able to achieve this using [debug registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register). However, these are only meant for debugging purposes, and should not be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called WaitOnAddress which is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706898(v=vs.85).aspx
It signals a waiting thread when the address is changed within the current process. I don't necessarily think this is the answer you're looking for if you're referring to doing this via IPC. If you are doing this via IPC though, you could do code injection and accomplish this with the same function.